# Joi required dynamic key

Tags: validation, typescript, hapi.js, joi

I am using Joi 10.6.0 in a Typescript project to validate the payloads on a series of requests. I am having the weirdest issue while validating a dynamic key in the payload:

```
validate: {
   payload: Joi.object()
         .pattern(/^id_[\s\S]*$/i, Joi.string().required())
         .keys({
             state: Joi.string().optional(),
             presentation: Joi.string().optional(),
  // etc
```

The idea is that I want the payload to include at least one key starting with `id_`. Alas, the `required` property on that pattern key seems to be totally ignored.

The regex matches the key correctly, and if I put other types of validation on the value, like `Joi.number()` the value is validated accordingly, but if I use `string().required()` and the value for `id_` is not in the payload, the validation, bafflingly, still passes. In short, any validation seems to be applied, bar `required`.

I am sure I am doing something stupid but I am stumped -- I use Joi every day and I've never had such issues.